# How to make the Required Message disappear for an inputText in PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a p:inputText component of PrimeFaces and I have set required="true" and requiredMessage="$$$$$$$$" also. After Displaying the $$$$$$$$$ message, these message and the highlighting of the input Text field MUST disappear for me.ie upon clicking a RESET button. How can I make the Required Message and highlighting of the p:inputText disapper up on clicking the reset button for eg:.

```
                        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username: "
                            styleClass="cssLabelclasslogin" />
                        <p:inputText id="username" label="Username" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Username is Required"
                            value="#{loginBean.username}" styleClass="loginFormcsstextBox">
                        </p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are looking for can be acheived with the p:resetInput component.

```
<p:commandButton value="Reset" update="username" process="@this"  >  
    <p:resetInput target="username" />  
</p:commandButton>
```

Also see:

[Primefaces - ResetInput](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/resetInput.jsf)

Comment: Hi @Emil Kaminski I am using PrimeFaces3.2 snapshot and it doesn't have p:resetInput componenet.